# Split, doesn't work first character

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a problem with the method `split`.
I have this regex:

```
String regex = "[\s|\,]+";
```

And I have these two strings:

```
String s1 = "19/2009 , 34.40";

String s2 = ",19/2009 , 34.40";   // this is the same string wiht "," in the start
```

I apply the regex to the two strings:

```
String r1[] = s1.split(regex);  
String r2[] = s2.split(regex);
```

In the first case I get `r1[0]="19/2009"` and `r1[1]="34.40"`, this is the correct result. But in the second case I get `r2[0]=""`, `r2[1]="19/2009"` and `r2[2]="34.40"`. This is wrong, it should be the same result for the second string as for the first, without the empty string. What do I need to change for that?

Comment: What language is this?  C#?  Java?

Comment: Can you preprocess the input strings?

Comment: Couldn't you just remove those empty strings? It would be easy to do

Comment: Your regex is strange. For one, you need to double the backslashes in a Java string. Then, do you really want to include a literal `|` in the list of split characters? It doesn't mean "or" inside a character class, you know. Also, no need to escape the comma. You probably want `String regex = "[\\s,]+"`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you gave `,` as a regex, `,` splits your string in two, so your string `,19/2009`  is split into two parts. The first part is before `,`, which is nothing so `""`, and the second part, which is `19/2009`, is in `r2[1]` and the third, separated by another `,`, is in `r2[2]=34.40`. Everything is working right.

Comment: Yes, the regex is producing exactly what you describe, but this is not what the poster is asking. The poster does not want the array to contain empty strings.

Comment: Ok, but can I build the regex to the split don't give me this empty string?

Comment: You can, but then `r1[0]` would become `",19/2009"` - you don't want that either, do you?

Answer (score 1):

using [Apache Commons' StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)...

```
String r2[] = StringUtils.strip(s2, ", ").split(regex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would leave the regex as it is and do this

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitArray));
for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    if (iterator.next().isEmpty()) { // remove empty indexes
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

It's a little bit longer but it gives you a `List` as an output which is much better that an array.